# dealing with digits less than 1

Tags: android, math

I want to get the results of the math below but  my code seems to wrong.Basically I want to get the amount after multiplying 100 by the amount entered which I presume that it will be a number less than 1 e.g 0.50. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String numberEntered = edtamount.getText().toString();

            try {
                if (numberEntered .matches("")){
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "please enter valid amount ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }else {

                    double number = Integer.parseInt(numberEntered );

                    if (number < 1) {

                        double resultsnewk = number * (double) 100;
                        NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("K0.00");
                        String formated = f.format(resultsnewk);
                        txtnewk.setText(" " + formated);


                    } else {

                    //Do nothing
                    }
```

Comment: What's the actual question? (And why an empty `else` block if you don't intend to do anything?)

Answer (score 0):

```
double number = Integer.parseInt(numberEntered );
```

doesn't make much sense,

```
double number = Double.parseDouble(numberEntered);
```

seems more intuitive.

`Integer.parseInt()` would throw a `NumberFormatException` on the input `"0.50"`.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now.